# Store fraction in string without SQL translating it into date serial

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

How do I get SQL Server to store a simple fraction (like "3/4") into a `varchar` column without SQL converting it into a date serial?

For example: when I try to store "3/4" it converts into "43193".

Now, if that were a date (although without a year?) I would appreciate that.
But I am trying to store a simple fraction (actually a music time-signature).
And "43193" is useless to me.

I am NOT trying to store it into any kind of date data type. I am trying to store it into a `varchar(64)`

Table definition:

```
hNbr (smallint, not null) sTag (varchar(16) not null) sDat (varchar(64) null)
```

insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO [tablename] ([hNbr], [sTag], [sDat]) VALUES('300', 'Time SIgnature', '3/4')
```

Comment: can you show the INSERT/UPDATE statement you are executing?

Comment: INSERT INTO [tablename] ([hNbr], [sTag], [sDat]) VALUES('300', 'Time SIgnature', '3/4')
I store hundreds of other values in scores of fields, but this is the only case that isn't working

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: hNbr (smallint, not null)
sTag (varchar(16) not null)
sDat (varchar(64) null)

Comment: This seems weird. What happens when you `SELECT CAST('3/4' AS varchar(64));`? Everything fine this way?

Comment: I tested you structure and your statement and '3/4' inserted without being converted.

Comment: Check actual DDL of this table: right click on it->Tasks->Script->CREATE TABLE. Check if there is any trigger. Btw, are you running this INSERT directly in SSMS or through some application?

Comment: SQL Server would never convert this. Must be whatever you are using at the front end. Something like Excel would do it every time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone to responded.  It must have been the application language that was doing the unwanted conversion.  It wasn't a (MS) SQL problem.

The web page was written in classic ASP VBScript.  When I re-wrote the web page, it works as expected now.